# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in web/mhswpindahprodi.det.php on line 221

Tags: php, string, runtime-error

Here is some code

```
TampilkanJudul("Mahasiswa Pindah Prodi");

    if (!empty($mhswid)) {
      $gos = (empty($_REQUEST['gos']))? 'KonfirmasiPindah' : $gos;
      $mhsw = GetFields("mhsw m
        left outer join program prg on m.ProgramID=prg.ProgramID
        left outer join prodi prd on m.ProdiID=prd.ProdiID
        left outer join statusmhsw sm on m.StatusMhswID=sm.StatusMhswID",
        'm.MhswID', $mhswid,
        "m.*, prg.Nama as PRG, prd.Nama as PRD, sm.Nama as SM, sm.Keluar");
      if ($mhsw['Keluar'] == 'Y')
        echo ErrorMsg("Tidak Dapat Dipindahkan",
          "Status Mahasiswa: <b>$mhsw[SM]</b> yang berarti sudah tidak
          dapat dipindah lagi.
          <hr size=1 color=silver>
          Pilihan: <a href='?mnux=mhswpindahprodi'>Kembali</a>");
      else $gos ($mhsw); // line 221
    }
    ?>
```

its geting error Fatal error:

> Function name must be a string in
>   /var/www/clients/client9/web31/web/mhswpindahprodi.det.php on line 221

Comment: try to echo $gos content..possibly your $gos content is empty

Comment: Unless you `var_dump` `$gos`, you won't fix that. Anyway for more safety you should be doing: `$gos = (!is_string($_REQUEST['gos']))? 'KonfirmasiPindah' : $gos;`

Comment: $gos shouldn't be empty, because you're already testing for empty values; but it could be a numeric value (e.g. '11') which would not be a valid function name.... better to test with function_exists() before trying to call

Answer (score 0):

```
  $gos = (empty($_REQUEST['gos']))? 'KonfirmasiPindah' : $gos;
```

Replace this line with:

```
  $gos = (empty($_REQUEST['gos']))? 'KonfirmasiPindah' : $_REQUEST['gos'];
```

It's pointless to test whether a variable exists, and then use a different variable instead ;)